# Text and Image zooming are different

Tags: html, css

I have an external provided image of a table and want to add a column in front of it.

The image as well as the input fields have a height set in pixels. Therefore, I expect that the zoom works equal on both elements.

I noticed that the the image zooms different than the text. e.g. in Firefox, the rows have the wrong height if it is zoomed too much in. What can I do?

http://jsfiddle.net/zw64q9x8/

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .blubb {
            height:16px;
        }
    </style>

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <input type="text" class="blubb" /><br />
                <input type="text" class="blubb" /><br />
                <input type="text" class="blubb" /><br />
                <input type="text" class="blubb" /><br />
                <input type="text" class="blubb" /><br />
                <input type="text" class="blubb" /><br />
                <input type="text" class="blubb" /><br />
                <input type="text" class="blubb" /><br />
                <input type="text" class="blubb" /><br />
                <input type="text" class="blubb" /><br />
                <input type="text" class="blubb" /><br />
                <input type="text" class="blubb" /><br />
                <input type="text" class="blubb" /><br />
                <input type="text" class="blubb" /><br />
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <img alt="" height="617" src="http://i.imgur.com/vS1RIi7.png" width="907" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't zoom in that way and hope it will keep working to that level of precision. The point is, zooming does not work very well with fractional pixels. It rounds the values, so if you have a 16 pixel high object and you zoom to 133%, it will be 21 pixels high rather than 21.3. When repeated 28 times, those differences add up!

But there are some ways you can keep the inputs in line with the rows in the image.
One trick is to put this in a table with 28 actual rows. So no `<br />`, but 28 individual `<tr>`s., and put the image in one column with a `rowspan`.

```html
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="blubb" /></td>
    <td rowspan="28"><img alt="" width="907" height="617" src="http://i.imgur.com/vS1RIi7.png" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="blubb" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="blubb" /></td>
    ...
    etc.
```

When you do that. each row will have 1/28 the height of the table, which will be the same as the height of the image, so this will always line up, no matter if the zoom factor causes rounding errors or not.

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/zw64q9x8/1/).